# Why can't I access this CSS property in a JavaScript function?

Tags: javascript

I can't access the `left` property of one image element in a JavaScript function when I set the property from within stylesheets but when I use inline styles on the image tag it works fine.

Here is my code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head id="Head1" runat="server">
        <title></title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function moveObjRight(obj) {
                var a = document.getElementById(obj);
                alert(a.style.left)
            }
        </script>
        <style type="text/css">
            #AS
            {
                top: 141px;
                left: 118px;
                position: absolute;
                height: 25px;
                width: 25px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
            <div>
                <img alt="asd" src="pic 3-4.jpg" id="AS" />
                <input type="button" value="Button" onclick="javascript:moveObjRight('AS');" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the computed styles properties. This can be achieved in a cross browser method with a simple function. Have a look on [quirks mode](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/getstyles.html) for an explanation of the following function.

```
function getStyle(el,styleProp) {
    var x = document.getElementById(el);
    if (x.currentStyle)
        var y = x.currentStyle[styleProp];
    else if (window.getComputedStyle)
        var y = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(x,null).getPropertyValue(styleProp);
    return y;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For Mozilla Firefox, check the [documentation for img](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/element/img).

In Internet Explorer, see *[<IMG> Property Pages Dialog Box](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/600ts169%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)*.

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion (not an answer), use [jQuery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery)!

You would be able to access the left property with the following code.

> $('#yourdiv').css('left');

Reference: *[.css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/)*

Comment: It is *[a meme](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19492#19492)*.